# Convert "float;#22.0000000000000" into just "22.0" in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, floating-point

I'm doing a `ToString()` on an object and the output I am getting is `float;#22.0000000000000`. I just need `22.0`.

**How do I achieve this in C#?**

Additional info:
The object is the value from a Number column in a SharePoint list. The value is being retried in my code with a CAML query. I'm sure it's the use of a CAML query that's causing me this issue. If I retrieve the item just by iterating through all the items in the list I don't have this issue, but this approach is not as efficient as a CAML query.

Update:
It seems it is not the `ToString()` that's causing this output. The object that I'm calling `ToString()` on already seems to be set as `float;#22.0000000000000`, so this is what's coming straight out of the CAML query.

Comment: can't you use substring to take the value?

Comment: Sure I can, but that wouldn't be a "proper" solution. I'd also like to understand why I'm getting this output in the first place.

Comment: You should not rely on ToString() to much, because it can be overridden. If the exact output includes "float;#" then it probably is overridden. Can't you inspect/check if there are public properties on the object that you can use?

Comment: Even before I do a `ToString()` the value seems to be set as `float;#22.0000000000000`, so it seems this is simply what's coming from the query. I can see this when debugging and inspecting the object. The object has no public properties.

Comment: Keep in mind that the various inspectors, like the watch window, in the debugger use the override .ToString() for a short description. Can you at least find out what the 'real' type of the object is?

Comment: I now have an answer, thanks for your input. The column I was retrieving was a Calculated column in SharePoint, and this is simply how SharePoint stores values internally in Calculated columns. When retrieving list items via CAML query, you have to do the conversion yourself with `item.GetFormattedValue("ColumnName")`. But if you programatically retrieve the item, the conversion is done for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use given code to get only 22.0

```
string value = "float;#22.0000000000000";
var number = value.Split('#')[1];
double num = double.Parse(number);
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString("0.0"));
```

> Result: 22.0

mentioned code should be work.

```
item.GetFormattedValue("ColumnName")
```

OR try this post

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fdef03db-9678-46cf-8ff7-03551f4b8466/how-to-convert-a-decimal-number-field-to-c?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'll only consider this solution as a last resort. I'd like to understand if there is a "proper" way of doing a conversion, and why I'm even getting this output.

Comment: I have edited my answer please go through the mentioned link in answer, this could be work for you.

Comment: `item.GetFormattedValue("ColumnName")` did the trick. Thanks!